# Button don't lose focus when disabled on Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, mozilla

When button is focused and then become disabled, focus is still on the button.

It makes browser unresponsive for keyboard events.

Problem does not occur on Chrome, because all disabled buttons lose focus automatically. Global listener seems to work but maybe you have better solution.

```
 window.addEventListener('click', ev => {
        if (ev.target instanceof HTMLButtonElement && ev.target.disabled) {
           ev.target.blur();
         }
 })
```

https://codepen.io/magdalena-chmura/pen/abOrERz?editors=1010

Comment: pls add this style when disabled.
button { pointer-events: none; }

Answer (score 0):

I know it is very late and probably you don't need it anymore, but here is working code to fix it on all visible buttons. You only need to call this function at the right moment:

```
initButtonObservers() {
  this.element.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('button').forEach((button) => {
    const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
      mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
        if (mutation.attributeName === "disabled" && mutation.target instanceof HTMLButtonElement) {
          mutation.target.blur();
        }
      });
    });
    const config: MutationObserverInit = { attributes: true };
    observer.observe(button, config);
  });
}
```